# Proxy model django from package

Tags: python, django, proxy-classes, action-mailbox

I have a problem in my code

```py
from mailbox import Message
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
        

class MyMessage(Message):
    class Meta:
        Proxy = True

    def creattask(self):
        task = Task(title=self.subject)


class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

I want to fill title attribute of Task model from subject  Message model. for that, I use createtask function.

However, when I go to the admin page I found Task(title) model empty !!
any help, please !!

Comment: You have save the instance you are creating. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save
or use `create` method on the manager directly https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.create

Comment: i saved the instance , how can i create method for teste it !!?

Answer (score 0):

yes i saved the instance

```
 def save(self, **kwargs):
     # some business rules here
     super(Task, self).save()
```

but title field  still empty